# How to perfectly center contents in an unordered list?

Tags: css

I have an unordered list of items and I want to make the contents perfectly centered on the page, no matter what the breakpoint/screen dimension is.  I don't know in advance how many items there will be.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this using just CSS?  I know this can be done with JavaScript, but I prefer using just CSS if possible.

Screenshot:
[image]

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/wrf39qev/1/

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/1"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/2"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/3"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/4"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/5"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/6"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/7"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/8"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/9"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/10"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay.  I will when there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?
ul comes with a default padding and margin and you need to specifically remove it.

**Edit**

Set a width to the ul, added margin:auto and floated the elements to the left. Does this help?

**Edit : 2**

Set display block to images and set width : 100% , height auto;

**Edit:3**

You can add width of 33% to the li(s) to ensure that the gap is same on either side. However if you want the gap to be the same and also if you want to fit as many images as possible, you will have to use media queries at breakpoints. Meaning, you need to write something like, "from this width to that width, I will need 5 images in one column hence (20%)" and so on. That is the only way.

This will move the content to the center and left align the items.

```css
ul { list-style-type: none;margin:0;padding:0; width:90%; display:block;margin: auto;}
li { 
    display: block;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


img{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
  }


@media only screen and (max-width:1200px){
    li{
        width:25%;
      }
  }


@media only screen and (max-width:900px){
    li{
        width:33%
      }
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/1"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/2"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/3"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/4"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/5"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/6"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/7"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/8"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/9"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/230/265/city/10"></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This is a good start, but I just want to center the rows that have a full amount of items.  If the last row doesn't fill up, is it possible to left align the content?  For example, if you look at the following screenshot, the item in the last row is lining up with the 2nd item of the penultimate row.  I would like it to line up with the 1st item.

Screenshot:
http://imgur.com/uoU5veF

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this does not work.  By setting the width of the li to be 33.33%, it will ensure that at most, 3 items will be on per line.  I want each line to fit as many images as possible before going to the next line.

Comment: Yeah, removed the 33% width condition. Is that ok now?

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I might be able to use some universal styling but I'll tackle this using media queries.  I can specify the width of the ul to accommodate how many items I want at specific breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ul to 100% width and no margin and use block for the li elements or else you will get multiple columns:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; width: 100%; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;}
li { 
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt, auto margins usually fixes most centering problems when it comes to images

```
li { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

or just

```
li { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `text-align: center` on your `<ul>`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrf39qev/8/)